# How do i divide in haskell and then return answer in a list

Tags: list, haskell, integer, typeerror, division

Hi there I am new to Haskell and was wondering if someone could educate me on division and why my code is not working. Any help/crit is appreciated

```
grades :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
grades a x y z =[(fromIntegral(a-x) / fromIntegral (x)) * fromIntegral(100)]
```

I want my code to calculate the percentage increase from x to a and then return it inside of a list.

The error:

```
 No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of `/'
    * In the first argument of `(*)', namely
        `(fromIntegral (a - x) / fromIntegral (x))'
      In the expression:
        (fromIntegral (a - x) / fromIntegral (x)) * fromIntegral (100)
      In the expression:
        [(fromIntegral (a - x) / fromIntegral (x)) * fromIntegral (100)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your type signature gives the result type as `[Int]` but the result of division  `(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a` is a `Fractional` type, which `Int` is not, as the error is telling us:

```
   No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of `/'
```

You can fix this by using e.g. `round`:

```
grades :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
grades a x y z = [round $ (fromIntegral(a-x) / fromIntegral (x)) * fromIntegral(100)]
```

Other possibilities are `floor` or `ceiling`, for a more "predictable" behavior. `round` uses banker's rounding:

```
> map round [0.5..10]
[0,2,2,4,4,6,6,8,8,10,10]
```

The functions are all methods of the `RealFrac` class:

```
> :i RealFrac
class (Real a, Fractional a) => RealFrac a where
  properFraction :: Integral b => a -> (b, a)
  truncate :: Integral b => a -> b
  round :: Integral b => a -> b
  ceiling :: Integral b => a -> b
  floor :: Integral b => a -> b
```

Or, if you want your grades to be more precise, you can change the type signature without changing your code at all:

```
grades :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [Float]
```

Comment: Surely we should be using `div` or `quot`, instead of converting to fractions and then rounding?

Comment: @amalloy not if I -- or rather, the OP -- want to experiment with rounding behavior. `div` has `floor` baked in, isn't it? (I've edited in the mean time)

Comment: @amalloy another argument is that we can't just drop the `fromIntegral`s and replace the `/` with the ```div```, the code must be rearranged as well. this means that using integral division makes this code more brittle, in addition to fixing the rounding behavior _implicitly_ (salient features are better stated _explicitly_, as a matter of good design). and if a logic ever changes, the corresponding code change must be done carefully... with the floats it just works. :)